# Can't detect hard drive on Macbook Pro

Tags: mac, macbook

I changed a few month ago the config of my Macbook Pro with the following:

- I bought a SSD hard drive
- I removed the hard drive of my Mac book Pro and installed there my brand new SSD
- Then I removed my DVD drive and installed my hold hard drive instead with a caddy

Everything was working great until today when I couldn't access anymore to my old hard drive because it is not detected anymore. Sometimes Mac OSX is mounting it but it takes like 15 min to browse a simple folder.

I opened my laptop to have a look at the problem. It seemed like the optical drive connector was not plugged correctly to the motherboard (that connector: http://cl.ly/2T0X2e1j0J1g47061d1t). So I plugged it correctly and reboot. It didn't fix my problem.
Then I tried to put my SSD in the caddy and to boot: no hard drive was detected. So I guess there is something wrong either with the caddy, either with the optical drive connector, or either with the plug that is on the motherboard.

So my question is, how can I know where the problem comes from?

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tried two drives in the caddy, replace the caddy and see if that works. If it doesn't fix it, then its probably the connector or the motherboard itself.

Additionally you could test the connector connections with an [Ohm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohmmeter)- or [multi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter)-meter. Infinite resistance = no connection.